# How to filter out atomic vectors from list in R?

Tags: r

I have very big list, every component of that list. I need to get the value of called of variable called `cv` . it work with other lists, but in some list I face with error:

```
Error in x$cvm : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

How can I filter out this vectors from my list before running my code?

Here is what my code do:

```
MES<-lapply(mylist, function(x) x$cvm[x$lambda == x$lambda.min])
```

it works well, but in some list, it's produce already mentioned error.

Answer (score 3):

`$` are valid e.g. for lists (and environments, but probably it's not your case). To filter out all elements which are not lists, call:

```
mylist2 <- mylist[sapply(mylist, is.list)]
```